# Text size vs other content size changing when zooming in on web page

Tags: html, css, fonts, size

I recently took up web programming, and this issue plagues my site. I set all the font sizes using px values in css and aligned everything using divs, absolute positioning, and more px values. It looks fine until I try zooming in and out, at which point the text size and page size decrease at different rates, resulting in comparitively huge text when zoomed all the way out. This also renders viewing the site on a mobile device completely impossible. I've read that font sizes should be specified with ems not pxs, but that didn't fix it.

What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

It's an easy problem to get into, particularly for a beginner. Consider moving divs to percentage values etc. In terms of mobile viewing and standard desktop browsing, I would suggest you try using a grid system.

One popular example which is very easy to use & I think is great for beginners is [960.gs](http://960.gs/)

I'm afraid without code snippets and your question being very generalised, its unlikely we can help.

There are also ready to go grid systems that shift the page around depending on screen size but I wouldn't recommend them until you are comfortable using [960.gs](http://960.gs/)

Answer (score 0):

I would also try http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/, it makes it very easy to create a nice looking site. As redditor mentions, using pixels can result in weird behaviors when zooming especially for positioning elements. I would try to use something like bootstrap or 960, or one of the other grid systems.